# Set directory index to .html file in Apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a Debian web-server with Apache2 installed and need to set in one directory DirectoryIndex to .html file (exactly this name - .html). But when I try to open page from browser it send 403 error. 
I've changed apache2.conf (set to allow .ht files), I placed .htacess file in directory and set in it:

```
DirectoryIndex .html index.php index.html
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

But it still not work and displays 403 error. What i doing wrong and what i forget to do?

Comment: Did you confirm the read privilege of the folder?

Comment: Yes, i even tried to set it to 777

Comment: @Evgeniy Skulditsky: I think you may also check your folder's owner and group .

Comment: Folder's owner and group i've checked at first of all ) I think that in some other place are additional rules about .ht files

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your apache log files? If not, you might want to try adding/changing [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) to get a better idea as to why Apache is giving you 403s.

Comment: LogLevel is set to debug, but there is no messages eigher in Access log or in Error log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.html">
        Order deny,allow
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex .html
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Ay, sure. Damien was right. There is a rule somewhere that blocks these kind of files. We are releasing them. The key here is the Order directive. Order deny,allow means that it is allowed by default unless there is a deny rule.

Comment: But there is one small problem: host.com/dir/ - working, but host.com/dir/.html - doesn't

Comment: There was additional rule in nginx config that disabled access to .ht files

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a rule somewhere in your apache file that denys access to files starting with a `.`. This is generally a Good Thing, as a lot of sensitive files start with dots (ie: .htaccess, .svn, .git, .htpasswd, etc etc).

You might be able to get around the issue with something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.html">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Files>
```

**Disclaimer**: This seems like a hack. I don't know what you're trying to do, but there's probably a cleaner, less error prone way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for good answer but i'm already do it in apache2.conf: <Files ".html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
I also tried your code but it still 403 error.